# Segmentation fault in "if" statement in C

Tags: c

The following program generates binary numbers of n numbers, with exactly k numbers "1". This does its job fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int n;
char arr[34] = {'\0'};
int sum = 0;

void TRY(int v) {
    if (v == n) {
        if (sum == 0) printf("%s\n", arr);
    } else {
        arr[v] = '0';
        TRY(v + 1);
        if (sum > 0){
            arr[v] = '1';
            sum--;
            TRY(v + 1);
            sum++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Nhap k, n: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &sum, &n);
    TRY(0);
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I replace line 8 with

```
if ((v==n) && (sum == 0)){
```

and delete the check sum == 0 on line 9, I get segmentation error.
I just want to know why it is happening.

Comment: Take this as the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger*. You can use the debugger to catch the crash when it happens, to see exactly where it happens in your code, and then also examine variables and their values.

Comment: Sounds like you have undefined behavior somwhere. It's probably unrelated to the check. Find which line that causes the segfault and the value of the variables there.

Comment: For what input to the program? You do recognize that `if(v == n) { if(sum==0) {a;} } else { b; }` differs from `if(v==n && sum==0) {a;} else {b;}` (hint: when the else part will be executed)!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a segmentation error because your code can't go below this line:

```
TRY(v + 1);
```

Your base case

```
if ((v==n) && (sum == 0))
```

could never be `true` unless `sum` is already 0, if you assign anything to `sum` other than 0, your base case will never be executed as it will never reach `sum--`, as your base case doesn't get executed, `v` will keep on incrementing, and at one point `v` will become greater than the size of `arr` and therefore causing a segmentation error.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, now I got it.

Your expectation is that the else branch will be run if and only if `(v==n) && (sum == 0)` evaluates to false. That's wrong. It will execute if `v==n` is false, regardless of `sum`. So the check is not equivalent.

However, the `printf("%s\n", arr);` will execute if and only if `(v==n) && (sum == 0)` is false.

I'd recommend using this printf statements in a situation like this:

```
printf("sum: %d v: %d n: %d\n, sum, v, n);
```

And then like this:

```
void TRY(int v) {
    puts("Entering TRY");
    printf("sum: %d v: %d n: %d\n, sum, v, n);

    if (v == n) {
        puts("Entering if");
        printf("sum: %d v: %d n: %d\n, sum, v, n);

        if (sum == 0) printf("%s\n", arr);
    } else {

        puts("Entering else");
        printf("sum: %d v: %d n: %d\n, sum, v, n);
```

Comment: The phrasing here is misleading (and technically wrong). When `v==n` is false, so is `(v==n) && (sum==0)`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I found out that `v==n` is likely to be reached before `sum==0` is, when `v==n && sum==0` is still false. Thus the code proceeds to try a higher `v`, that's when segmentation fault comes.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @IngoBürk I forgot about the ambiguity for "or" in natural language. :D